# Got "two named subpatterns have the same name" when combining 2 regex into one

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to combine 2 different regex with the same names into one and got the error message like this:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation
>   failed: two named subpatterns have the
>   same name at offset 276 ...

One regex looks like this:

```
'%<div class="artikkelen">[\s\S]*?<h2>(?P<title>[\s\S]*?)</h2>%'
```

The other looks like this:

```
'%<div id="article">[\s\S]*?<h1>(?P<title>[\s\S]*?)</h1>%'
```

I could combine them in the following way without problem:

```
'%(<div class="artikkelen">[\s\S]*?<h2>(?P<title>[\s\S]*?)</h2>|<div id="article">[\s\S]*?<h1>(?P<title2>[\s\S]*?)</h1>)%'
```

But I don't like this way because I use 2 names. I'm wondering whether there is a better way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Box (boxoft...Simple & Great)

Comment: Give one of them a different name.

Comment: This is one of the many, many painful places where PHP does not use Perl compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine them like this instead:

```
%<div (class="artikkelen"|id="article")>[\s\S]*?<h[12]>(?P<title>[\s\S]*?)</h[12]>%
```

This is not exactly the same as it was before but might be good enough.

Comment: Be aware this regex can accept ``div class="artikkelen"><h1>...<h1></div>`` when it is not possible in the OP regex (the precision wanted depends on the context). To get exactly the same regex, see @electricdarrell answer with subpatterns

Answer (score 42):

I found this page looking for a way to have two (or more?) named subpatterns with the same name, and I found [this page](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=5089) with the answer (relevant excerpt here)

> **Duplicate names**
>
> If you are using named patterns you can now have the same name multiple times, provided you put the "(?J)" option in your pattern. For example:

```
    Match: (?J)(?P<name>Ni.+)|(?P<name>Fr.+)
```

> This would match "Nick" or "Fred", and whichever one matched, the named pattern "name" would be set to it.

just contributing knowledge back to the universe

Comment: This is the actual solution to the problem which maintains all reqs.

Comment: `(?J)` enables the regular expression modifier for the remainder of the pattern. You can also pass `J` as a regular modifier to `preg_match()` & Co; i.e., `/(?P<name>Ni.+)|(?P<name>Fr.+)/J`, as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php