# Using different names for subpatterns of the same number with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I'm having a hard time getting my head around what exactly is being numbered in my `regex` subpatterns. I'm being given the `PHP` warning:

`PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: different names for subpatterns of the same number are not allowed`

When attempting the following:

```
$input = "A string that contains [link-ssec-34] and a [i]word[/i] here";
$matchLink = "\[link-ssec-(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\]";
$matchItalic = "\[i](.+)\[\/i]";
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    "/(?|(?<link>$matchLink)|(?<italic>$matchItalic))/",
    function($m) {
        if(isset($m['link'])){
            $matchedLink = substr($m['link'][0], 1, -1);
            //error_log('m is: ' . $matchedLink);
            $linkIDExplode = explode("-",$matchedLink);
            $linkHTML = createSubSectionLink($linkIDExplode[2]);
            return $linkHTML;
        } else if(isset($m['italic'])){
            // TO DO
        }

    },
    $input);
```

If I remove the named capture groups, like so:

```
"/(?|(?:$matchLink)|(?:$matchItalic))/"
```

There's no warnings, and I get matches fine but can't target them conditionally in my function. I believe I'm following correct procedure for naming capture groups, but PHP is saying they're using the same *subpattern number*, which is where I'm lost as I'm not sure what's being numbered. I'm familiar with addressing subpatterns using `$1`, `$2`, etc. but don't see the relevancy here when used with named groups.

---

### Goal

Incase I'm using completely the wrong technique, I should include my goal. I was originally using `preg_replace_callback()` to replace tagged strings that matched a pattern like so :

```
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\[link-ssec-(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\]/",
    function($m) {
        $matchedLink = substr($m[0], 1, -1);
        $linkIDExplode = explode("-",$matchedLink);
        $linkHTML = createSubSectionLink($linkIDExplode[2]);
        return $linkHTML;
    },
    $input);
```

The requirement has grown to needing to match multiple tags in the same paragraph (My original example included the next one `[i]word[/i]`. Rather than parsing the entire string from scratch for each pattern, I'm trying to look for all the patterns in a single sweep of the paragraph/string in the belief that it will be less taxing on the system. Researching it led me to believe that using *named capture groups* in a `branch reset` was the best means of being able to target matches with conditional statements. Perhaps I'm walking down the wrong trail with this one but would appreciate being directed to a better method.

### Result Desired

```
$input = "A string that contains [link-ssec-34] and a [i]word[/i] here";
$output = "A string that contains <a href='linkfromdb.php'>Link from Database</a> and a <span class='italic'>word</span> here."
```

With the potential to add further patterns as needed in the format of square brackets encompassing a word or being self-contained.

Comment: Why you're using [branch reset `(?|`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)  use `(?:` non-capture group instead or drop the outer gruop if unneeded.

Comment: @bobblebubble I've added my understanding in an edit for clarity

Comment: @biscuitstack you've added your *goal* but you never actually define what the end target is (you've basically indicated what your end process is and the premise for your question, but not end result). What exactly are you trying to do with `[link-ssec-XX]` and `[i][/i]` pieces? Are you editing the original string somehow? If so, what does the output resemble?

Comment: @biscuitstack I think you have a typo in your results. Did you mean `<span class="italic">word</span>`?

Comment: @ctwheels My example showed that I needed to differentiate between whether `[link-ssec-XX]` or `[i]word[/i]` was matched while (a) replacing what was matched (b) required a callback to use sections of matched pattern, and (c) being as efficient as possible in terms of system overhead rather than running several `preg_replace_callback()` functions. What I turn any of the matched strings into is irrelevant and may bloat the question but I've done so just incase. See edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about the warning:

> PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: different names for subpatterns of the same number are not allowed

Your pattern defines named matchgroups. But your pattern is using alternations (`|`) as well, meaning a whole part of the pattern does not need to be matched as all.

That means, that the named pattern `link` can appear with the match-number `1`, but `italic` can also appear with match-number 1.

Since there is an alternation BOTH the matches can only be the same "number", hence they are only allowed to have the same NAME:

```
@(?|(?<first>one)|(?<first>two))@
```

would be allowed.

```
@(?|(?<first>one)|(?<second>two))@
```

throws this warning.

Comment: What you say is true but it is also really annoying and I see no reason for it. So can you provide a work-around? Date Example, not working due to this exact issue: `/^(?|(?<y>\\d\\d(\\d\\d)?)-(?<m>\\d\\d?)-(?<d>\\d\\d?)|(?<d>\\d\\d?)\\.(?<m>\\d\\d?)\\.(?<y>\\d\\d(\\d\\d)?))$/`

Comment: Found the solution: Do not use `(?|` but instead set the `J` flag like `/...regex.../J`. Props to Electric Darrell with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166444/1050382)

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understand what I've done (but will look into it now) I did some trial and error on @bobblebubble comment and got the following to produce the desired result. I can now use conditional statements targeting named capture groups to decide what action to take with matches.

I changed the `regex` to the following:

```
$matchLink = "\[link-ssec-(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\]"; // matches [link-ssec-N]
$matchItalic = "\[i](.+)\[\/i]"; // matches [i]word[/i]
$output = preg_replace_callback(
        "/(?<link>$matchLink)|(?<italic>$matchItalic)/",
        function($m) { etc...
```

Hopefully it's also an efficient way, in terms of overhead, of matching multiple regex patterns with callbacks in the same string.

Comment: The branch reset group is for sharing the same group index in an alternation ([example](https://regex101.com/r/p53vNo/1)). If you use this feature and name the group, it needs to have the same name. It looked contradictory to use this feature if you want to distinguish between groups (which is the default behaviour).